# Default style is not working

Tags: css

I'm learning CSS, and trying to make a default rule:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

It's not working, and I don't know why... can you please point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Try to add `@charset "utf-8";`

Comment: After giving `padding: 0px` in `*` selector, again you are applying `padding: 50px` in `body` selector.

Comment: do you have othe external stylesheet loaded afterwards..?? because lastly added style will be in effect.

Comment: What is not working? What does the end result look like? What do you want it to look like instead?

Answer (score 1):

Its certainly because **your body has padding of `50px;` which overwrites the rule of html as far your page's body** is **concerned**.

**Edit** :

```
body
{
 margin : 0px;
 padding : 0px;
}
```

hope you problem is solved now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

LIke this `please write` `margin` and `padding` in `body` tag

you have used padding:50px; in your body tag please remove padding,thats * not working properly

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VkVA8/1/)**

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;}
```

here both of working  please check demo

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;}
```

Comment: it's still giving me margin and text indentation :(

Comment: @Daryl please provide your source code which one you have a try this?

Comment: @Daryl coding style DOESNOT matter. But how are you saying that padding and margin is not applied?

Comment: here's the code picture shot http://postimg.org/image/q2kcw1pfx/
here's the output: http://postimg.org/image/vvc1dn7kn/
it's spose to apply "0 margin" to everything by default? it's still indented :(

Comment: @Daryl in may i sure try this body tag please give margin:0; padding:0

Answer (score 0):

Add first you should include a normalize stylesheet. The different browsers have different default styles and this stylesheet will bring one standard to all browsers.

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

I think this will help you ;)

Comment: the *{} default rule applies on IE while doesn't work on google chrome? how can i resolve this :(

Comment: @Daryl Have you tried removing the comment inside the `<style>`? Compare http://jsfiddle.net/geaQh/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/geaQh/2/ - see Petr's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

On CSS part don't use html comment. Thats reason, why doesn't work your css part.

Comment: This is a good point, although I assume OP only added the comment after he was unable to make the css work. HTML comments inside `<style>` will indeed screw up the following rule. http://jsfiddle.net/geaQh/1/ - the correct syntax for comments in css is `/* comment here */`

Answer (score 0):

Your are using `unordered list` to create menu.

by default, It has those intend properties, you can override by using below code, which is not advised.

```
*{
 margin : 0px;
 padding : 0px;
}
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/VkVA8/2/) & [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/VkVA8/3/)

Also change `background-color : ABC;` to `background-color : #ABC;`